# Mysql special characters not updating correctly

Tags: php, mysql, updating

I had update a column in a table with the value

> "Size: Inside rabbit :   31 ½” x 50 ¼ “  Rabbit min 3/8"

.But it was updated like

> "Size: Inside rabbit :   31 Â½â€ x 50 Â¼ â€œ  Rabbit min 3/8".

When i put the query in phpmyadmin it updated correctly.

Thanks,
A.John Melchior.

Comment: Put this before you run your update query on PHP: mysql_set_charset("UTF8");

Comment: @davidvelilla I think you must mean `mysqli_set_charset("UTF-8");` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) ;-)

Comment: @davidvelilla its not working..

Answer (score 1):

I have inserted the given text from phpmyadmin successfully. I have added '' and then insert the string inside another "". This is the query I've used:

```
INSERT INTO `sample_table`(`user_input`) VALUES ('"Size: Inside rabbit : 31 ½” x 50 ¼ “ Rabbit min 3/8"');
```